# Jquery autocomplete error - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am looking in the console on my website and receiving this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on this line of code:

```
$("#category").autocomplete({
```

i have included JQuery using:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and the rest of the code is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var data = [{"value":"Broadband"},{"value":"Domains"},{"value":"Hosted Exchange"},{"value":"Networking"},{"value":"Offsite Backup"},{"value":"Phone Lines"},{"value":"VoIP"},{"value":"Web Hosting"}];
        $("#category").autocomplete({
            source:data,
            select: function(e, ui) {
                e.preventDefault() // <--- Prevent the value from being inserted.
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="Domains" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you linked all correctly? It works me http://jsfiddle.net/d2upbk19/.

Answer (score 0):

if your order is like

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var data = [{"value":"Broadband"},{"value":"Domains"},{"value":"Hosted Exchange"},{"value":"Networking"},{"value":"Offsite Backup"},{"value":"Phone Lines"},{"value":"VoIP"},{"value":"Web Hosting"}];
        $("#category").autocomplete({
            source:data,
            select: function(e, ui) {
                e.preventDefault() // <--- Prevent the value from being inserted.
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="Domains" />


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

it wont work..

the two scripts must be above your ready() function

Comment: luckily its not like that :) - the scripts are at the top of the page

Comment: then you maybe develop on file protocol, change //code.jquery ... to `http://code.jquery` ...

Answer (score 0):

The above file was also being included in another file on the website. this has been removed and fixed the issue